# android gps spikes issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am getting a very stupid problem

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, ll);
    float spd = myLoc.distanceTo(previousLocation) / (myLoc.getTime() - previousLocation.getTime());
```

previous location is the `myLoc` stored last time `onLocationChanged` was called i-e each after 1 second.

Now my problem is, sometimes it gives extremely big peak values. making `spd` go way higher than it usually is.

Anyone can tell how can i reduce this

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few recommendations:

1. Check `Location.hasSpeed()` to see if this information is provided for you.  It may be more reliable than your calculation, though I don't know anything about the algorithm used to produce this value.
2. Check `Location.getAccuracy()` to decide when to ignore a particular fix for calculating speed.
3. Read these tips thoroughly to see an example of how to be selective when dealing with GPS results.  They could be too old or too imprecise to be used for speed. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Updates
4. For an app I worked on, I implemented a filter that compared the current location to the two previous locations and used the lowest calculated speed.  You may need a more or less complex method to determine speed that will be useful for you.